# Declare a field for each method that matches a pointcut in AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj, aop

I want to declare a private field for each method that matches a pointcut.

For example, I have User class and I want to add some fields(like `private long internalId`,`private String internalName`,...) for each getter.

```
public class User {

  private long id;
  private String name;
  //some other fields ...

  public long getId() {
      return id;
  }

  public String getName() {
        return name;
  }

  //some other getters ...
}
```

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't get the aim..How would you access those field then as thy are private ?

Comment: Private or public is not the problem.I want to declare multiple fields and methods by one aspect.